# The most suitable verb for the expression "print a book"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions

I was wondering whether you could help me in choosing the most suitable word.

Can I say that "a book is currently being printed" or is there a better expression? What I am trying to say is that the book will be available in a month or two but the people need to wait until it is "printed".

The word "print" doesn't sound too good IMHO, but as I am not a native speaker I suppose an advice from a person more fluent in the language than I am would be quite helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Your choice is good, we usually assume that the printing process will also include all those other printing related tasks, such as editing and delivery.

Comment: @TrevorChristopherButcher That would, I think, depend on how familiar you are with the process of book production. If a book is in production, I would assume it to be anywhere between manuscript submission (and acceptance) and final binding; if it’s in printing or being printed, I would assume the editing process is complete and the book has been sent to the printers. I would, however, consider binding to be part of ‘printing’, even though it’s often done by a different provider.

Comment: people need to wait until it is available...

Comment: You might try "publish" rather than "print".

Answer (score 2):

[**At the press**](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/at-the-press) is an alternative that has a more professional ring.

In academic journals one sometimes sees "*In press*" as a citation for works that are being printed and the full details not yet known.